# How to randomize products for a specific department?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here's my category structure:

```
• Department
  • Category
    • Sub-Category
```

Here's my database:

[image]

I want to display 6 random products from a specific department. So for example, when a user goes to view a department page I want all products in that department only. The problem I'm having is I cannot figure out a way to get only the department, for some reason I can only get the products from Category ... I need to go one more level.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN products_categories pc
ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN categories c
ON pc.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE c.category = 119
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6
```

119 would be the department id, but my query comes up empty because I cannot go that far down.

**EDIT**
I created an SQLFiddle to make things easier for everyone ... very cool tool ;)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/964ed/3

**EDIT** I'm thinking I need to explain better

So I have my categories three deep; Department, Category, and Sub-Category. The department has no products tied to it, all the products are tied to the sub-categories. Since my products aren't tied directly to my department, how the heck can I make a query that will retrieve everything under a department? I'm trying to get everything under Firearms since that has the most products. When I query using Firearms id (119) I get nothing? But when I use one of the Sub-Categories id, I get results? So, I'm guessing I need to do some type of sub select or something, but not sure. Hopefully that clears things up :)

**EXPECTED RESULTS**
Using `119`, which is the `category_id` for `firearms`, I would like to get the following records:

```
(143, 131, 'single-shot')
(144, 131, 'semiautomatic')
(145, 131, 'bolt-action')
(146, 131, 'pump & lever action')
(171, 130, 'bolt-action')
(174, 136, 'safe')
(178, 130, 'single-shot')
(179, 130, 'pump & lever action')
(180, 130, 'semiautomatic')
(182, 181, 'shotgun ammunition')
(183, 181, 'rimfire ammunition')
(184, 181, 'centerfire ammunition')
(185, 181, 'handgun ammunition')
(186, 120, 'cooking')
```

Comment: What do you mean "I cannot go that far down"? Also, shouldn't your query just be:

Comment: SELECT *
FROM products p
JOIN products_categories pc
ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
 AND pc.category_id = 119
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6

Comment: Hey user1888440 - I tried your query and no results were found when there are eight in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a site that explains exactly what I'm looking for:
http://code-slim-jim.blogspot.com/2010/06/mysql-find-grandparentsgrandchildren.html

SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/964ed/97

Answer (score 1):

Try this pleaes and comment: Since you are specifying the department id, it doesn't make much difference with either `left` or `inner join` here. I have used my own sample data.

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53bae/2)

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN prod_categ pc
ON p.id = pc.pid
LEFT JOIN category c
ON pc.cid = c.id
WHERE c.id = 119
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6
;


| ID |    NAME | PID | CID |
----------------------------
|  1 |   ebook |   1 | 119 |
|  2 | artbook |   2 | 119 |
```

---

### EDIT:

Looking at your sample data, it seems there is not `category 119` in the cross referenced table : `products category`. So I tried with `category id 182` and changed the `limit 2` as per your sample data..

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/964ed/32)

Query:

```
SELECT p.*, pc.category_id
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN products_categories pc
ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN categories c
ON pc.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE c.category_id = 182
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
;
```

Comment: @Mike please comment once you have seen the demo and tried out :) it's just a matter of the way you have done the table relationships. In my sample I don't have lots of data rows.. so the output might not make much sense to you, as to get 6 random rows ;)

Comment: tried your code and had no luck. I'm adding a snap shot of data in my database to help better understand my relationships.

Comment: @Mike let me try with your data :) So based on your sample data, can you show us what is your expected result as well please.

Comment: @Mile any possibility if you could paste the table sample from mysql itself instead of the table image (to make it faster for typing into the sqlfiddle...) ;)

Comment: @Mike Give my answer a try.  I think your LEFT JOINs are messing you up.

Comment: @BobDuell in this query it doesn't seem to matter if a left or inner as he is giving the specific department id... It's anyway good to give yours a try. Only I wished if his sample data were not an image..

Comment: @bonCodigo I'm not sure "where" the `WHERE` clause is processed in relation to the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses.  Given the example, it should certainly be an `INNER JOIN`; that's the only thing I could think of.  And I agree, it would be much easier for you to help Mike if he posted that sample data as plain text.

Comment: I added a fiddle to make this easier on everyone ;)

Comment: @Mike there is no `category id 119` in your `products_categories` table....that could be the very reason you are not getting the data..

Comment: @bonCodigo is there a way I can get the root of a specific category. For example, (180, 130, 'semiautomatic') -> (130, 119, 'rimfire') -> (119, NULL, 'firearms'). Firearms is the root category, so I want all records that fall under the firearms category.

Comment: Yes Ofcourse :-)  you may simply add c.name, c.parent into it. And you can the either select specifying root/parent. Let me know if it is helpful ( I am on mobile unable to write the last piece of code in fiddle): `where c.category_name = ...` or try `c.parent = 119`...

Comment: @bonCodigo - Ultimately what I need is: STEP 1 - Get all Categories with a `parent` of `119`. STEP 2 - Get all the Sub-Categories with a `parent` matching the `category_id` from step 1. I think that is the step I need to take. What do you think?

Comment: Have you tried this: `where c.category = 119 or parent = 119`? Based on the sample data can you show us your ideal expected results?

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I didn't get anything returned. I will put the expected results in my description. Thanks for your time BTW ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a derived table.  And note that your `WHERE` clause defeats the `LEFT JOIN`, so you may as well just do an `INNER JOIN` instead, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM products p
   INNER JOIN products_categories pc
   ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
   INNER JOIN categories c
   ON pc.category_id = c.category_id
   WHERE c.category = 119
   ) x
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6
```

Comment: I added a fiddle to make this easier on everyone ;)